# How to change color of specific cells using check marks

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to "find" specific cells. Meaning that if I check a checkbox I want it to find all cells in a row that contain the letter "A" and color them. All I can do is color the whole row/column, but not specific cells. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168410/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule like this:

`=$C$1 * search("a", A2)`

...where cell `C1` contains a checkbox and cell `A2` is the top left cell of the range you want to format.

If your intention is to put checkboxes on all rows, replace `$C$1` with `$C2` or similar reference to the checkbox column.

See [Lance's explanation](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/60050658?msgid=60238341) of how absolute and relative addresses work in a conditional formatting custom formula rule.